# Gitlab expand calendar.json

Tags: gitlab, repository, heatmap

I work since few years on a project. On my profile I only see the heatmap of the last 12 month. Is there a easy way to see the other past years?

The heatmap use these URL to read the data. Is it possible to use parameters?

https://<gitlabURL>/users/<username>/calendar.json

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any params to receive prior activities with the *calendar.json* URL.

But with the [events API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/events.html) you can get all activities of the past three years.

With the call below you receive all your events since 2018-09-01.

```bash
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/events?after=2018-09-01&scope=all"
```